# How to Insertion Sort?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

What is missing?

less a little
It's almost done

Also is there a way to make it faster?
thanks

```
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        int[] data = {4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2};
        sort(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void sort(int[] data) {
        int j, pivot;
        // insert data[i] to sorted array 0 ~ i - 1
        // begins from i = 1, because if the array has only one element then it must be sorted.
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
            pivot = data[i];
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && data[j] > pivot; j--)  // shift data[j] larger than pivot to right
            {               
                data[j+1] = data[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make it faster by using an `O(n*log(n))` algorithm like quicksort.

Comment: And can you please show the actual output and what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a problem when you are interchanging the values between data[j+1] and data[j]. You overwriting the value from data[j+1], without to keep it in a temporal variable and put it in data[j].

```
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        int[] data = {4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2};
        sort(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] data) {
        int tmp, pivot;
        // insert data[i] to sorted array 0 ~ i - 1
        // begins from i = 1, because if the array has only one element then it must be sorted.
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            pivot = data[i];
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0 && data[j] > pivot; j--)  // shift data[j] larger than pivot to right
            {
                tmp = data[j + 1];
                data[j + 1] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As @dan1st suggest, try to use quicksort if you want a better performance. A good explanation of the quicksort algorithm and it's Java implementation you could find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)